# How to handle PUT requests in RESTful API?

Tags: php, request, put, http-method

I want to use `PUT` request for update operation in my web service but I don't know how to handle PUT because there is no inbuilt variable like `$_PUT`.

I tried `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);` 
now if I `print_r` the `$post_vars`, it is showing

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJnBh3L2DKmMjdVmG Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fruit" vanana ------WebKitFormBoundaryJnBh3L2DKmMjdVmG Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items" 1 ------WebKitFormBoundaryJnBh3L2DKmMjdVmG--
```

How can I get the exact parameters that is passed while making `PUT` request?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your problem

Your PUT request has `multipart/form-data` content-type.
So `parse_str` function cannot parse it.

#### Solution

You must make PUT request with `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Then you can parse it with `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post_vars);`

#### Notes

You won't be able to upload files. Because files require to use `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score -1):

There is a super global `$_SERVER` which contains **REQUEST_METHOD**

It can be used to identify the request method used to access the page; i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.

So you can use this at your server to identify the put request.

Comment: I want to get the parameter and it's value from that PUT request. As you can see in my post that I have parameter named "fruit" and value "vanana" and "items" value is "1". I want this parameters.

Comment: You can access these parameters and their values from $post_vars like $post_vars['fruit'] $post_vars['items']

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fruit in F:\xampp\htdocs\tempput.php on line 14

This is the error!